# Relationships and mongodb array in Laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-mongodb

I have a collection:

```
{
    ...
    users: ["..some objectID", "another objectID"]
    ...
}
```

Can I use relationships to get information about these users from the User model or do I need to make a separate query?

I understand that I can extract the `ID` and make a separate query using `whereIn`, but this will be very inefficient especially with pagination when a large amount of data is retrieved